# How to disable link previews in Android Messages app?

Tags: sms, google-messages

Android Messages app can show the preview of the link in an SMS.  For example:

[image: example]

I am trying to figure out a way to detect if the request comes from a preview so I don't get false positive visits.

Is there a way to disable the link previews?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Since you mentioned that the question has been asked before, it might be helpful to provide some links as additional context. Also, I assume Android Messages is the AOSP/Google Messages app, but mentioning the device model might also help in case the messaging app is different. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To disable link previews on Android/Google Messages app:

1. Tap the overflow menu (3 vertical dots) at the top-right corner
2. Select **Settings**
3. Select **Automatic previews**
4. Tap either **Show all previews** and/or **Show only web link previews** to disable